# Markdown table strings to two dimensional array converter implementation in C#

Tags: c#, strings, array, formatting

I am attempting to implement a converter which can convert `List<string>` type [markdown table](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#Tables) into two dimensional array `string[,]`.

**The experimental implementation**

```
public static class Converter
{
    public static string[,] ToTwoDimArray(in List<string> input)
    {
        return ConcatenateVertical(GetTitleRow(input), GetContents(input));
    }

    private static string[,] ConcatenateVertical(in string[] source, in string[] newRow)
    {
        int columnLength = source.GetLength(0);

        string[,] output = new string[2, columnLength];

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnLength; columnIndex++)
        {
            output[0, columnIndex] = source[columnIndex];
        }

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnLength; columnIndex++)
        {
            output[1, columnIndex] = newRow[columnIndex];
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static string[,] ConcatenateVertical(in string[,] source, in string[] newRow)
    {
        int columnLength = source.GetLength(1);
        int rowLength = source.GetLength(0) + 1;

        string[,] output = new string[rowLength, columnLength];

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowLength - 1; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnLength; columnIndex++)
            {
                output[rowIndex, columnIndex] = source[rowIndex, columnIndex];
            }
        }

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnLength; columnIndex++)
        {
            output[rowLength - 1, columnIndex] = newRow[columnIndex];
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static string[,] ConcatenateVertical(in string[] source, in string[,] newRows)
    {
        if (source.GetLength(0) != newRows.GetLength(1))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Width isn't match", nameof(source));
        }
        
        int columnLength = source.GetLength(0);
        int rowLength = newRows.GetLength(0) + 1;

        string[,] output = new string[rowLength, columnLength];

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnLength; columnIndex++)
        {
            output[0, columnIndex] = source[columnIndex];
        }

        for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < rowLength; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnLength; columnIndex++)
            {
                output[rowIndex, columnIndex] = newRows[rowIndex - 1, columnIndex];
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static string[,] GetContents(in List<string> input)
    {
        int columnLength = GetTitleRow(input).Length;
        int rowLength = input.Count - 2;

        string[,] output = new string[rowLength, columnLength];
        for (int rowIndex = 2; rowIndex < input.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            var rowData = GetRow(input, rowIndex);
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnLength; columnIndex++)
            {
                output[rowIndex - 2, columnIndex] = rowData[columnIndex];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    private static string[] GetTitleRow(in List<string> input)
    {
        return GetRow(input, 0);
    }

    private static string[] GetRow(in List<string> input, in int rowIndex)
    {
        return RowConstructor(input[rowIndex]);
    }

    private static string[] RowConstructor(in string input)
    {
        char[] charsToTrim = { ' ' };
        return Array.ConvertAll(input[1..^1].Split('|').ToArray(), element => element.Trim(charsToTrim));
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> strings = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
strings.Add("|1|2|3|4|");
strings.Add("|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|");
strings.Add("|5|6|7|8|");
strings.Add("|9|10|11|12|");
strings.Add("|13|14|15|16|");
strings.Add("|17|18|19|20|");
strings.Add("|21|22|23|24|");
strings.Add("|25|26|27|28|");
strings.Add("|29|30|31|32|");
strings.Add("|33|34|35|36|");
strings.Add("|37|38|39|40|");

string[,] result = Converter.ToTwoDimArray(strings);

int columnLength = result.GetLength(1);
int rowLength = result.GetLength(0);

for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowLength; rowIndex++)
{
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnLength; columnIndex++)
    {
        Console.Write($"{result[rowIndex, columnIndex]}\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The output of the above test:

```
1       2       3       4
5       6       7       8
9       10      11      12
13      14      15      16
17      18      19      20
21      22      23      24
25      26      27      28
29      30      31      32
33      34      35      36
37      38      39      40
```

If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Comment: This does not seem to work as intended.  You specify that each column should be centered with `:-:` but each is left aligned.  This example seems too trivial to catch any problems.  For instance, what about determining the width of each column?  Here you have 2 digits so that's trivial.  What if you the 2nd column had something with 8 characters and the last column has something with 10 characters?

Comment: @RickDavin Thank you for the comments. I am trying to retrieve data in Markdown table format and construct in `string[,]` type structure. Because the data structure used here is only `string[,]`, the alignment hasn't been recorded. In the listed example, I am trying to print the constructed `string[,]` result and this is nothing about the alignment `:-:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` keyword in a parameter list is used to pass an argument by reference. This is used to speed up passing big structs. Since strings and lists are of a reference type, a reference is passed anyway. Specifying `ref`, `out` or `in` makes them be passed a reference to a reference. This makes only sense for `ref` or `out` parameters when the method must replace the original object of the caller.

See also: [in parameter modifier (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier).

---

You can make the `RowConstructor` more robust by allowing the leading or the trailing `|` to be optional (as specified in the link you provided). The name "constructor" is more suited for a class. I prefer verbs for methods.

`String.Split` returns an array already. `.ToArray()` is superfluous.

```cs
private static string[] CreateRow(string input)
{
    int start = input[0] is '|' ? 1 : 0;
    int end = input[^1] is '|' ? 1 : 0;
    return input[start..^end].Split('|');
}
```

---

We can do it without this complicated `Concatentate..` methods by inserting the rows directly into the output table.

```cs
private static void InsertRow(string[,] table, string[] row, int rowindex)
{
    int numColumns = table.GetLength(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        table[rowindex, i] = row[i];
    }
}
```

---

We can treat the header row the same way as we do with the data rows, except that we must get it before creating the output table to determine the number of columns. Therefore, I created a method that creates the output 2d-array and returns it as a tuple together with the reader row.

```cs
private static (string[,] table, string[] header) CreateTable(IList<string> input)
{
    string[] headerRow = CreateRow(input[0]);
    int numColumns = headerRow.Length;
    int numRows = input.Count - 1; // without the horizontal line row.
    string[,] table = new string[numRows, numColumns];

    return (table, headerRow);
}
```

---

Now we can write the main method easily.

```cs
public static string[,] ToTwoDimArray(List<string> input)
{
    var (table, header) = CreateTable(input);
    InsertRow(table, header, 0);

    for (int rowIndex = 2; rowIndex < input.Count; rowIndex++) {
        string[] dataRow = CreateRow(input[rowIndex]);
        InsertRow(table, dataRow, rowIndex - 1);
    }

    return table;
}
```

---

My solution has 40 lines of code and is still very readable, compared to your solution with 98 lines of code. This has mainly been achieved by replacing 3 lengthy concatenation methods by a single row insert method.

Remove some vertical lines at the begin and end of lines in the test input to test the new `CreateRow` method.

Comment: Thank you for answering. About the `in` parameter part, if the purpose is to ensure that the reference type argument is not able to be modified, is there any other better way?

Comment: No, you can't ensure that members of a reference type are modified. Passing by value (the default) will only ensure that the reference itself won't be modified outside the method. Sure, you can pass the list as [IReadOnlyList<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=net-5.0) (the list implements it), but you cannot avoid that it will be cast back to [List<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) (`if (readonlyList is List<T> list) list.Add("hello");`)

Comment: There is the possibility to wrap the list into a [ReadOnlyCollection<T> Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=net-5.0) with the [List<T>.AsReadOnly Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.asreadonly?view=net-5.0). But this would have to be done by the caller. Otherwise it makes only sense for return values. For value types, passing by value will always pass a copy to the method.